# Why Cycles baking makes artifact lines to the texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, baking

For some reason when I bake diffuse color out from Blender, I get to my baked texture strange long lines and I was not able to find anyone else having similar problems. [image]

The left one is the baked dice and the selected one is the high poly. Then I have a close-up view of the baked texture. In node editor, I have the high poly material.

UV-islands are not overlapping. Texture size is big enough that this should not happen because of it. The low poly object is not overlapping anywhere with the high poly.

Here is the blender file, if you wanna examine it better to see: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sr5yeo1scf8g4bv/dices.blend?dl=0

I was using TexTools addon to bake, but I don't believe it to be the reason for this. I've seen similar lines before and I have slight idea that it has something to do with texture coordinates, but I don't understand enough myself to tell. Basically, the object coordinates is doing something "illegal" and I don't know what.

Can someone explain to me what is then causing these and how to avoid it in the future?